# How to fix flutter devtools opening on the wrong URL?

Tags: flutter, dart

I changed flutter channel from stable to master then returned to stable, and after this when I try to open devtools from android studio now it opens the URL `http://127.0.0.1:9101/...` which is a blank white page. I searched for a solution and couln't find any. But when just changed the `9101` to `9100` in the URL, then it worked and devtools opened normally, but now every time I have to do this manually. How can I fix it so that android studio opens it automatically?

Comment: maybe a `flutter clean` helps?

Comment: @IvoBeckers no it doesn't, neither does creating a new flutter project

Answer (score 0):

In my case -- all I did was to clear the cookies for Dart Devtools and it worked!